How to handle elevation in Angular Material 18+?
According to the material 3 spec, different levels of elevation are supposed to be handled by color instead of shadow. However in my Angular Material 18 project, all backgrounds seem to have the same color/elevation (eg toolbar, navbar and cards). How is this supposed to work exactly? According to the docs (https://material.angular.io/guide/elevation) I am supposed to use classes, but they don't seem to be doing anything in version 18+. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: https://m3.material.io/styles/elevation/overview

This seems to be a known P4 bug in angular material. It's still not fixed, it was raised for angular 15.
bug(mat-card): mat-elevation-zx no longer working for mat-card after upgrade to version 15 - Github issue
Do upvote that issue so that it gets fixed in the future.

The reason you are getting this issue is that the theme styles are having more precedence than the elevation class that is why the box shadow does not get applied.
As for the temporary workaround.
All you need to do implement the temporary workaround by user GoodGuyGregory
@for $i from 0 through 24 {
  .mat-mdc-card.mat-elevation-z#{$i} {
    @include mat.elevation($i);
  }
}

We recreate the elevation classes at the angular stylesheet level, so that the precedence issue is resolved.
If for other angular material components, try the below fix, which I use !important to guarantee the override is applied.
@for $i from 0 through 24 {
  .mat-elevation-z#{$i} {
    @include mat.elevation($i) !important;
  }
}


So the final output will be:
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

$theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

body {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

@include mat.core();
@include mat.color-variants-backwards-compatibility($theme);

@for $i from 0 through 24 {
  .mat-mdc-card.mat-elevation-z#{$i} {
    @include mat.elevation($i);
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
Angular material elevation documentation

Thank you! This seems to work. The only problem is that it seems shadows are used for elevation. Which is the material 2 way. Do you know how I can use colors (the material 3 way) instead?

@henkenstein Looking at the docs, this is the M3 way, you are pointing to the M3 docs only.

I know that's what the angular website says, but according to the spec it is diffrent (see https://m3.material.io/styles/elevation/overview).

@henkenstein There is no way to show elevation by changing the element surface color, they are setting box shadow and showing the depth, same as what angular material is doing, if you want you can do an inspect element on the material element and you will see a box shadow applied, same as how angular material does it!

UPDATE: I found a way to do this. In case anyone else is struggeling with this:
To implement elevation using colors in Angular Material 18, you need to use the surface and surface-container colors. These colors are part of the new theming system introduced in Material 3.
Here is an example of how you can define and use these colors in your Angular Material theme:
// custom-theme.scss

@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$light-theme: mat.define-theme(
  (
    color: (
      theme-type: light,
      primary: mat.$azure-palette,
      tertiary: mat.$blue-palette,
    ),
  )
);

@mixin mdc-surface-colors($theme) {
  $colors: (
    'surface',
    'surface-container-lowest',
    'surface-container-low',
    'surface-container',
    'surface-container-high',
    'surface-container-highest'
  );

  @each $color in $colors {
    --mdc-#{$color}: #{mat.get-theme-color($theme, $color)};
  }
}

:root {
  @include mat.all-component-themes($light-theme);
  @include mat.typography-hierarchy($light-theme);
  @include mdc-surface-colors($light-theme);
}

  /* styles.css */

.surface {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface);
}
.surface-container-lowest {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface-container-lowest);
}
.surface-container-low {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface-container-low);
}
.surface-container {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface-container);
}
.surface-container-high {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface-container-high);
}
.surface-container-highest {
  background-color: var(--mdc-surface-container-highest);
}

Source: Medium article.
